# How to add dictionary to smartcn analyzer in ElasticSearch?

Tags: analyzer, elasticsearch, smartcn

I can see stopwords.txt, coredic.mem files in smartcn jar file, .mem file is binary. And I got the source from https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-smartcn, but there's no dictionary.

How to add or modify dictionary to smartcn analyzer in ElasticSearch?